# Excel 2013: Refresh data connection failing, tries to open the file instead

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

`EDIT:` I might have solved it, without knowing what the cause was. I'm still running tests to determine if it sticks, but from a user where the connection worked as expected I exported a connection file and then saved the workbook while the data connection was set to always use this connection file.

We're working with a couple of macro-activated workbooks that are all stored on a network share. To simplify the situation: workbook A fetches some data from workbook B. `Refresh All` normally updates the workbook as intended. All good so far.

For some users, the data connection *seems* to fail somehow, and Excel then resorts to trying to open the entire file instead of just pulling the table. Granted, if we let it open the file, the update goes through. But the added overhead of opening and closing that particular file is not really acceptable (it's resource heavy).

I'll reiterate that it does not occur for all users, and for those it occurs for it occurs consistently.

I don't know if it's a permission issue, since all the users can open all the files. Even the ones who experience this issue can open every file on the share manually without any trouble and without having to re-authenticate or some such.

How do I start troubleshooting this? I'm thinking it has to do with authentication somehow, but how do I find out where/how/why it's failing? The data connection is set to use the logged in user's credentials.

Answer (score 0):

So the fault wasn't anything of what I thought it was. Turns out that Excel can't pull the desired table when the file is opened by someone else, unless the local instance of Excel can open a read-only version first.